# Detecting object in an image

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

currently I am struggling in implementing an algorithm to locate an object in an image. Suppose I have 100 training sets that all have a cat in there and each has the correct coordinate of each cat. My first idea is to create a fixed-sized square and traverse through the image. For each collection of pixels contained in the square, we can use it as a point for Support Vector Machine algorithm.

The problem is that I am not sure how to do that since usually, each point represents each class (has object or has no object) and it usually has a simple d features, while for this case, it has a dx3 matrix as its features (each features has RGB value).

A simple help will be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question well, applying machine learning for image Processing and computer vision is a bit different from Other kinds of problems. main difference is that you should somehow overcome the issue of locality and scale. does all kitties always appear in the specific coordinate (x,y) ?! of course not! they can be anywhere in the scene. so how is it possible to give a specific point to SVM for an object? it will not be generalized at all. This is the reason almost all basic operation in computer vision has something to do with convolution operation to extract features independent from their location. A pixel alone carries zero useful information, you need to analyse groups of pixels. there are 2 approach you can take:

1. classic methods:

use OpenCV to perform noise removal, edge detection, feature extraction using methods like SIFT and feed those features to a model like SVM, not the raw unprocessed pixels. feature extraction means to reach from **d** features to **k** more meaningful representation of inputs where usually (k < d) if not always.

2. Deep Learning:

Convolutional Neural networks(CNNs) Have shed lights on many Computer vision tasks which were far beyond reach until recently and more importantly with frameworks like **Keras** and **tensorflow** most problems in computer vision is just programming tasks to be honest and doesn't require much knowledge as one needed before. because (CNNs) extract features themselves and you don't need to do the **feature engineering** anymore which requires a well educated and knowledgeable person on the task.

so, choose whatever method you see fit for kitty detection =^.^= .